# Lightning components not loading in a new org

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I recently migrated my lightning components to a newly created org. But the lightning components are not loaded in the newly created org.
Has anyone experienced similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to some updates for lightning component access.
Go to critical updates section and check for something like 'Enforce Lightning Components Access Checks'. Deactivating that may fix this.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. It worked now!  But is it a good idea to deactivate a critical update?

Comment: Its not a good practice. you have to find some workaround in the meantime.